# why my bind dns server show the below logs

Tags: dns

When I view the /var/log/messages, it shows the below logs:

```
Jun  1 16:33:51 dns13 named[1796]: client @0x7feac0084200 172.22.81.149#51759 (imap.mail.gxu.cn): query failed (SERVFAIL) for imap.mail.gxu.cn/IN/A at ../../../bin/named/query.c:8580
Jun  1 16:33:51 dns13 named[1796]: client @0x7fead40c59d0 172.22.81.149#50899 (imap.mail.gxu.cn): query failed (SERVFAIL) for imap.mail.gxu.cn/IN/A at ../../../bin/named/query.c:8580
Jun  1 16:33:51 dns13 named[1796]: client @0x7fead40c9af0 172.22.81.149#63975 (imap.mail.gxu.cn): query failed (SERVFAIL) for imap.mail.gxu.cn/IN/A at ../../../bin/named/query.c:8580
Jun  1 16:33:51 dns13 named[1796]: client @0x7feab40aaf30 172.22.81.149#50232 (imap.mail.gxu.cn): query failed (SERVFAIL) for imap.mail.gxu.cn/IN/A at ../../../bin/named/query.c:8580
Jun  1 16:33:51 dns13 named[1796]: client @0x7feadc0b15e0 172.22.81.149#49862 (imap.mail.gxu.cn): query failed (SERVFAIL) for imap.mail.gxu.cn/IN/A at ../../../bin/named/query.c:8580
```

Why? How can I resolve my problem?

my named.conf is:

```
//
// named.conf for Red Hat caching-nameserver 
//

acl "campusnet" {
  127.0.0.1/32;
  172.16.0.0/12;
};

options {
    directory "/var/named";
    dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    /*
     * If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
     * to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
     * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
     * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
     * port by default.
     */
    // query-source address * port 53;

    auth-nxdomain no;

        //allow-query {any;};
        allow-query {campusnet;127.0.0.1;};

        allow-query-cache {campusnet;127.0.0.1;};

        allow-recursion {campusnet;127.0.0.1;};

        recursive-clients 1000000;

        forward first;

        forwarders {221.6.4.66;58.240.57.33;};

    listen-on-v6 {
        any;
    };

        //dnssec-enable yes;
        //dnssec-validation yes;
        //dnssec-lookaside auto;

};

// 
// a caching only nameserver config // 
controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndckey; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
//
    zone "." IN {
        type    hint;
        file    "named.ca";
    };

        zone "16.28.210.in-addr.arpa" IN {
                type master;
                file "db.16.28.210";
        };
//
        zone "139.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "10086.cn" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "sina.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
//                forwarders {221.228.255.1;218.2.135.1;};
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "sina.com.cn" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
//                forwarders {221.228.255.1;218.2.135.1;};
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "126.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
               forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
//        zone "163.com" IN {
//                type forward;
//                forward first;
//                forwarders {221.228.255.1;218.2.135.1;};
//        };
//
//        zone "163.com" IN {
//                type forward;
//                forward first;
//                forwarders {202.195.144.6;202.195.144.8;};
//        };
//
        zone "jsrcsb.cn" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "taobao.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
//                forwarders {221.228.255.1;218.2.135.1;};
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
        zone "tmall.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
//                forwarders {221.228.255.1;218.2.135.1;};
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
        };
//
//        zone "youku.com" IN {
//                type forward;
//                forward first;
//                forwarders {202.195.144.6;202.195.144.8;};
//        };

//
        zone "youku.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
//                forwarders {221.131.143.69;112.4.0.55;};
        };
//
        zone "ykimg.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
//                forwarders {221.131.143.69;112.4.0.55;};
        };
//
        zone "soku.com" IN {
                type forward;
                forward first;
                forwarders {114.114.114.114;8.8.8.8;};
//                forwarders {221.131.143.69;112.4.0.55;};
        };
//    LOGGING

        logging {
                channel default_log {
                        file "/var/log/named.log" versions 10 size 1000m;
                        severity info;
                        print-time yes;
                        print-category yes;
                };

                category queries { default_log; };
                category lame-servers { null; };
        };
```

My DNS server is a recursive for users, when there are few users, there are no error logs, but when there are many users the errors are generated.